# Stub request if it contains keyword

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to stub requests from rspec file if it contains the keyword `zimpler` no matter what is the POST address and the content.

```
  stub_request(:post, "http://www.example.com/").
             with(body: "zimpler")
             to_return(:status => 200, :body => xml_file, :headers => {})
```

is there a way to implement this?

Comment: Does this work? `stub_request(:post, /.*/).with(body: /zimpler/)`

Comment: Yes, but only the post request. The body is not working for some reason.